# DDWRT Bridge Question

Tags: networking, dd-wrt, bridge

I recently setup a bridge and I have a few questions.  If the signal from router 1 is precieved as weak on the bridge router (router 2), what can I do to make the signal stronger?

Condition: I do not have access to the first router.

Hypoth: Can I increase the signal strength of router 2?  Will this provide a stronger link between the two routers?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think increasing the strength of router 2 will do anything. It would only increase the signal *out*, not *in*.

However, you could always try to install gain-boosting antennas on router 2 (or both routers).

That's really about all you can do.

(If you don't have access to router 1, does that mean you're piggybacking off of someone's wireless? :) )

Comment: So I'm wondering how does router 2 receive signal?  Using the same antennas it uses for out?